# Log4PostSharp for PostSharp 2.0 and .NET framework 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, postsharp, log4postsharp

I have a C# project targeting .NET framework 2.0. I also want to use PostSharp 2.0 Community Edition + Log4PostSharp. The problem is that it's not possible to use Log4PostSharp because it targets 3.5 framework. Also it's not possible to change Log4PostSharp's target framework to 2.0, because PostSharp.Sdk (2.0) is built against 3.5 framework.

Any suggestions what can be done to use Log4PostSharp 2.0 in a project targeting 2.0 framework?

Comment: no idea, unfortunately.  I managed to get things working with .Net 4.0; getting it backwards compatible with 2.0 might be a stretch.

Comment: Any particular reason you can't make your application target .NET 3.5 or better?  (There may be, but it's worth asking.)

Answer (score 0):

I checked the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/postsharp-user-plugins/source/browse/#svn/trunk/1.5) for Log4PostSharp. It's not in Nuget so you'll need to manually download and compile either version 1 or 1.5 of log4postsharp to include with your project. Both of those versions are build against .NET 2.0. Alternatively, you can try out [log4netAOP](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Log4NetAOP/) which is also supposed to work with PostSharp.